# Using javascript key event set fixed height for particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

Used webix,to create datatable that contains combo editor. These combo has drop down list, it gets cut when we enter any key. As these list is dynamically generated. I want to assign some fixed height for this list. I used below code,

```
on:{
   onkeypress:function(){
    $('.webix_popup').css("height","100px");
    $('.webix_list').css("height","100px");
   }
 }
```

I tried the above code but it didn't work for all keys, it works when i entered c, d, g, m, n, p, q key from keyboard.
I am not getting these behavior. Please can anybody tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To define fixed height, you can set it in the `suggest` property (just using Webix config, no need to use JQuery):

```js
{
    view:"datatable",
    columns:[
      { id:"year", editor:"combo", collection:years,
       suggest:{
         height:100,
         body:{
           autoheight:false
         }
       },
       header:"Released" , width:100},
      { id:"votes", editor:"text", header:"Votes", width:100}
    ],
    editable:true,
    // ...
}
```

https://snippet.webix.com/v2kkyacx